# EJS unable to access DOM elements causing undefined

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am trying to select DOM elements via VanillaJS or jQuery. Either way they are producing undefined within my ejs file.

I load all of my libraries at the top of ejs.

In middle of the page I have a simple

```
<% if (somevariable < 1) { %> 
  <!-- do something -->
   <script> document.getElementById("showorders").style.visibility = "hidden" </script>
  <% } %>
```

Further down the page I have a table with id "showorders".

All i want to do is set the visibility of the table to hidden if the statement is true. Else continue to run down the page and do normal process.

Why is the values undefined?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might occur because in your script there is a reference to an element which does not exist.
You should wait for the DOM load event.

Vanilla

```
<% if (somevariable < 1) { %> 
<!-- do something -->
<script> 
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded, function() {
       document.getElementById("showorders").style.visibility = "hidden";
   }, false);
</script>
<% } %>
```

jQuery

```
<% if (somevariable < 1) { %> 
<!-- do something -->
<script> 
   jQuery(function() {
       jQuery("#showorders").css("visibility", "hidden");
   });
</script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: nice choice :-)

Answer (score 1):

When the browser encounters a `script` tag it stops parsing the page and runs the script.  This is how `document.write` is able to add content at the current position in the page.

If you want your script to run after the DOM has been fully parsed, you should listen for the DOMContentLoaded event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("showorders").style.visibility = "hidden"
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Also very helpful comment. As you noted, I was trying to declare before DOM was fully loaded causing undeclared.